# A question about the "Required reviews completed" and "under review"

Tags: paper-submission

I submitted my paper to a very good journal. After two months and in the first round of revision, I received comments from four reviewers requesting major revisions. I edited my manuscript as they suggested and submitted the revised version. After 4 months and in the second round of revision, I again received comments from four reviewers in that three of reviewers directly recommended that our paper should be accepted for publication, and a reviewer requested major revision. I again edited my manuscript as the reviewer suggested and submitted the revised version. After 4 months, my paper status was changed to "Required reviews completed", but after two weeks it was changed to "Under review" again. Could you guide me what it means and is it possible the reviewers reject it despite their first opinions?

Comment: The question is clear and straight. Why did people vote down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rejection is always possible, but they have a lot invested in the paper and you have been cooperating. One possible issue if some of the latest reviewers are new, rather than the ones who have been looking at it, is that a new review might have different ideas than the others. Some editors will resolve it, but some will make you go round and round.

I was once in a serial review situation when I got a request to make changes that would essentially put the work (a book) back where it started. The editor finally stepped in to break the cycle.

It can be hard to please everyone, but you seem to be doing your best here.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering my question.